# Customizing Support Action Bar / Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I recently started Android programming, all is good and dandy, but I've came across a problem that I couldn't find an answer to, and I really diged hard for 4 days so far.

My app uses support action bar, and to be specific "**android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity**". Long story short, I couldn't handle most of the stuff applicable to an Action Bar to this support one.

My app uses this support action bar by default due to setting up my mini sdk version to 14.

I want to be able to build an action bar from scratch, and customize it, since the default action bar is not responsive to my customization in styles.xml, etc.

I don't mind using Holo theme library instead of AppCompat.

So the question here, how can use **Action Bar** instead of Support Action Bar?
How can I extend my java class to use that instead of the support one?

Because none of the online customizing solutions are applicable to the support action bar.

A bit foggy description so I apologize for that.

Comment: Which customizations are you talking?

Comment: what exactly is the `minSdkVersion` of your app?

Comment: minSdkVersion is 14 as mentioned above. And as for customization, I wanna change the color of the background of the actionbar alone.

Comment: Why do you need support library if your minVersion is 14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new project, and select the minimum API level as 15. When you do this, the `appcompat-v7` library will not be required for this project as it is for projects with `minSdkversion` < 15. In this project, the classes `android.app.ActionBarActivity` and `android.app.ActionBar` will be used by default, i.e. the native AOSP classes and not the ones from the support library.

The following will let you have an `ActionBar` with custom background color as you want it, on API level 8 and above.

**STEP 1.** In your `res/values` folder, define an XML file `theme.xml` and add the following to it:

```
<resources  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="DefaultActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:targetApi="11">@style/MyActionBar</item> 
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item> 
        <item name="android:actionBarSize" tools:targetApi="11">@dimen/action_bar_wrap_content</item> 
        <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/action_bar_wrap_content</item> 
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background" tools:targetApi="11">@color/actionbarbgcolor</item> 
        <item name="background">@color/actionbarbgcolor</item>
        <item name="android:height" tools:targetApi="11">@dimen/action_bar_wrap_content</item>
        <item name="height">@dimen/action_bar_wrap_content</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

In the same folder make another XML file `colors.xml` and add the following to it:

```
<resources>
    <color
        name="actionbarbgcolor">#00FF00
    </color>
</resources>
```

and to the existing file `dimens.xml`, add the last line:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

    <!-- Optional, in case you wish to increase the default width of the Action Bar. -->
    <dimen name="action_bar_wrap_content">55dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

In place of `#00FF00` above, use the hex color code for the background color you wish to use in your `ActionBar`.

**NOTE:** The above will work assuming you are using the `appcompat-v7` library. If not, then you'll have to use one of the `Holo.Light` themes instead of `AppCompat.Light`, and there will be other changes as well.

**STEP 2.** In your manifest file, you must add:

```
android:theme="@style/DefaultActionBarTheme"
```

to every `<activity` declaration if that `Activity` has the `ActionBar`.

Try this. It will work.

Comment: That's one workaround I thought of. I guess I have to sacrifice the support for ICS.

Comment: If all you want to do is change the color of the ActionBar, that can be done very easily and there's no need to override the `ActionBar` class just for that (and which would be a lot of work).

Comment: I tried all the suggested solutions online. They change the background color of the entire activity, i just want to change the color of the bar itself.

Comment: I'll edit my answer and give you the solution I used ... hang on

Comment: @Yousef Imran: I've posted the solution.

Comment: @Zygotelnit, be kind and wait for me to try it tomorrow. Thank you very much though. Family emergency.

Answer (score 2):

Zygotelnit answer works but you have to omit the ["tools:targetApi="11"] from item declaration otherwise it will give you an error for some reason.

On the other hand, I've found a much shorter and easier but not so optimized solution.While searching through the actionBar class and playing around here is the answer:

1. In your activity.java, go down to

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   ```
2. Anywhere appropriate in that method, write the following code:

   ```
   ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
   actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new  
   ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#D62D20")));
   ```

You replace the color code by any color code of your choosing. It's obviously a hex color code.

Comment: Yes this works too ... the method I have used is part of a general approach for customizing many different aspects of  `ActionBar`, and for keeping all the code in one single place. Generally, in Android it is preferred that styles, themes and animations should be controlled through XML. Just imagine if you had to put that code in every `Activity`. But thanks for sharing this approach too :)

Comment: I think your method is a better approach since you don't want to overload your java with graphics handling, it takes so much CPU and memory resources. The most efficient way is to use XML files for UI the way you Zygotelnit have. So thanks for the help mate @Zygotelnit .